# Toggle map Markers with CheckBox isChecked kotlin using if/else can not be null

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to use CheckBox's to have a user select which map marker's to display. the CheckBox's are in another activity. I have tried using the CheckBoxID.isChecked, but it states can not be null. Neither of the check box's will be checked until a user clicks them.

I have tried to add ?: and !! but that wouldn't work either. Is there another way to toggle/show/hide markers on the map? I'm very new to this so I don't know if I misunderstood the if/else or when statements or what.
Thank You!

Here is the MapsActivity code:

```
package com.example.truckersbestfriend
```

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
OnMapReadyCallback,
GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener,
GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener{

```
private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
private lateinit var lastLocation: Location
private lateinit var preferenceProvider: PreferenceProvider




private var lastSelectedMarker: Marker? = null

private val loves = mapOf(
        // LOVES TRUCK STOPS
        "LOVES282" to LatLng(37.013610, -94.544720),
        "LOVES727" to LatLng(36.568478, -95.218046),
        "LOVES295" to LatLng(36.162585, -95.342562),
        "LOVES255" to LatLng(35.485822, -95.149915),
        "LOVES636" to LatLng(36.719111, -95.629642),
)



private val taPetro = mapOf(

        // PETRO TRUCK STOPS
        "PETRO354" to LatLng(37.006505, -94.551619),
        "PETRO316" to LatLng(35.465525, -97.474443),
)


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    preferenceProvider = PreferenceProvider(applicationContext)





    btnLocations.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, Locations::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }


}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true)
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
    setUpMap()
    addMarkersToMap()
}

override fun onMarkerClick(marker: Marker): Boolean {

    lastSelectedMarker = marker

    if (marker.position == loves.getValue("LOVES282")) {
        val intent = Intent(this, loves282::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    } else
        if (marker.position == loves.getValue("LOVES727")){
            val intent = Intent(this, loves727::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    return false


}


companion object {
    private const val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1
}

private fun setUpMap() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
        return
    }
    mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true


    mMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL


    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(this) { location ->
        if (location != null) {
            lastLocation = location
            val currentLatLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 12f))
        }
    }

}

override fun onInfoWindowClick(marker: Marker)  {
}

private fun addMarkersToMap() {

    val lovesCheckBox = checkBoxLoves
    val taPetroChecoBox = checkBoxTaPetro

    if (lovesCheckBox.isChecked){
        addLovesMarkersToMap()
    }


    if (taPetroChecoBox.isChecked) {
        addTaPetroMarkersToMap()
    } else return
}


private fun addLovesMarkersToMap() {




        val placeDetailsMap = mutableMapOf(


                "LOVES282" to PlaceDetails(
                        position = loves.getValue("LOVES282"),
                        title = "LOVES282",
                        snippet = "I44 X 4",
                        isVisible = true


                ),


                "LOVES727" to PlaceDetails(
                        position = loves.getValue("LOVES727"),
                        title = "LOVES727",
                        snippet = "I44 X 283"
                ),

                "LOVES295" to PlaceDetails(
                        position = loves.getValue("LOVES295"),
                        title = "LOVES295",
                        snippet = "US 412/US 69"

                ),

                "LOVES255" to PlaceDetails(
                        position = loves.getValue("LOVES255"),
                        title = "LOVES255",
                        snippet = "I40 x 287"
                ),

                "LOVES636" to PlaceDetails(
                        position = loves.getValue("LOVES636"),
                        title = "LOVES636",
                        snippet = "US 169/AIRPORT RD"
                )

        )




        // place markers for each of the defined locations
        placeDetailsMap.keys.map {
            with(placeDetailsMap.getValue(it)) {
                mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                        .position(position)
                        .title(title)
                        .snippet(snippet)
                        .icon(icon)
                        .infoWindowAnchor(infoWindowAnchorX, infoWindowAnchorY)
                        .draggable(draggable)
                        .zIndex(zIndex)
                        .visible(isVisible)
                )

            }
        }


}

private fun addTaPetroMarkersToMap(){

    val placeDetailsMap = mutableMapOf(

            "PETRO354" to PlaceDetails(
                        position = taPetro.getValue("PETRO354"),
                        title = "PETRO354",
                        snippet = "I44 X 4",
                        isVisible = true

            ),

            "PETRO316" to PlaceDetails(
                    position = taPetro.getValue("PETRO316"),
                    title = "PETRO316",
                    snippet = "I35/I40 X 127"
            )




    )


    // place markers for each of the defined locations
    placeDetailsMap.keys.map {
        with(placeDetailsMap.getValue(it)) {
            mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                    .position(position)
                    .title(title)
                    .snippet(snippet)
                    .icon(icon)
                    .infoWindowAnchor(infoWindowAnchorX, infoWindowAnchorY)
                    .draggable(draggable)
                    .zIndex(zIndex)
                    .visible(isVisible)
            )

        }
    }
}
```

class PlaceDetails(
val position: LatLng,
val title: String = "Marker",
val snippet: String? = null,
val icon: BitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(),
val infoWindowAnchorX: Float = 0.5F,
val infoWindowAnchorY: Float = 0F,
val draggable: Boolean = false,
val zIndex: Float = 0F,
val isVisible: Boolean = true)

}

here is the activity where I have the checkBox's:

class Locations : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var preferenceProvider: PreferenceProvider



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_locations)

    preferenceProvider = PreferenceProvider(applicationContext)

    onLovesCBClick(view = checkBoxLoves)
    onTaPetroCBClick(view = checkBoxTaPetro)






    buttonToMap.setOnClickListener {




        val intent = Intent(this, MapsActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)


    }


}

fun onLovesCBClick(view: View) {
    if (view is CheckBox) {
        val checked: Boolean = view.isChecked

        when (view.id) {
            R.id.checkBoxLoves -> {
                if (checked) {
                    val loves = checkBoxLoves

                    preferenceProvider.putBoolean(constants.KEY_LOVES_CHECKBOX, loves.isChecked)

                }
            }
            else -> {
            }
        }


    }
}

fun onTaPetroCBClick(view: View) {
    if (view is CheckBox) {
        val checked: Boolean = view.isChecked

        when (view.id){
            R.id.checkBoxTaPetro -> {
                if (checked) {
                    val petro = checkBoxTaPetro

                    preferenceProvider.putBoolean(constants.KEY_PETRO_CHECKBOX, petro.isChecked)

                }
            } else -> {

        }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Any Idea's on what I can do to get past the checkBox must not be null? I've tried everything that I could find, but nothing is working.

Comment: you just add sign "!!"

Comment: @andika_kurniawan I have tried the val loves = checkBoxLoves.isChecked !! but it states Unnecessary non-null assertion (!!) on a non-null receiver of type Boolean. This is the run error:  java.lang.NullPointerException: checkBoxLoves must not be null

Comment: could you give me full source code ? you can whatsapp me if you want

Comment: @andika_kurniawan I have edited the post to contain the full code for the MapsActivity and the LocationsActivity where I have the checkbox's. Sorry for the very late response.